# How to filter QSortFilterProxyModel using QStringList?

Tags: c++, qt, model, qsortfilterproxymodel

I need to filter a QSortFilterProxyModel by QString values from a QStringList (m_shownElements). I have created some code, but it doesn't work yet. I need to show only the rows containing the values from the QStringList. How can I get this working? Do I need to loop trough the QStringList or is there a better way?

```
bool ProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    if (m_filterEnabled)
    {
        QModelIndex index0 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);
        for (int i = 0; i < m_shownElements.size(); i++)
        {
            if (sourceModel()->data(index0).toString().contains(m_shownElements[i]))
            // What now?
        }
}
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
bool ProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    if (m_filterEnabled)
    {
        QModelIndex index0 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);
        for (int i = 0; i < m_rows.size(); i++)
        {
            if (sourceModel()->data(index0).toString().contains(m_rows[i]) && m_shownRow)
                return true; //element should be shown
            else if (sourceModel()->data(index0).toString().contains(m_rows[i]) && !m_shownRow)
                return false; //element should NOT be shown
        }
        if (m_shownRow)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    } else
        return true; //no filter -> show everything
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your almost done. All you have to do is return true/false depending on whether the row should be show or not:

```
bool ProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    if (m_filterEnabled)
    {
        QModelIndex index0 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);
        for (int i = 0; i < m_shownElements.size(); i++)
        {
            if (sourceModel()->data(index0).toString().contains(m_shownElements[i]))
                return true;//element should be shown
        }

        return false;//not in the list -> don't show
    } else
        return true;//no filter -> show everything
}
```

And regarding your second question: I don't think there is an easy way to make it more efficient, correct me if I'm wrong. But before you spend hours in optimizing this, try out if it is fast enough first.

Comment: This works for a small tables. It gets stuck when using for large tables. Does this search in all columns or just in the first one? I only need to compare the values from the QStringList to the first column values...

Comment: You called `sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);` - thus only the first column will be compared.

Comment: I have optimized my code to make it faster. From now on, it will compare the size of the shown rows list to the size of the hidden rows list. It will filter the proxy model by the smallest list :)

Comment: @Engo `QList` (and consequently `QStringList`) is a _terrible_ data structure. Using a hash-set (`QSet<QString>`) will give you O(1) lookup instead of O(N).

Comment: @Rostislav Would this improvement be noticeable? My program still hangs when filtering by a "big" QStringList (26 elements). Do you think this is causing it?

Comment: @Engo Very likely.